# I don't know Extrapolation Method for initial value ODE

Tags: numerical-methods

my text book burden

$ y'(t)=f(t,y), a \leq t \leq b ,y(a)= \alpha$

apply for the extrapolation technique

we let $ h_0 = \frac{h}{2}$ and use Euler method with $w_0=\alpha$

$ w_1 = w_0+h_0f(a,w_0)$

and then midpoint method

$ t_{i-1}=a ,t_i=a+h_0=a+\frac{h}{2}$ to produce

approximation to $ y(a+2h_0)$

$ w_2=w_0+2h_0f(a+h_0,w_1)$

$y_{1,1} = \frac{1}{2}[w_2+w_1+h_0f(a+2h_0,w_2)] $

then why this form results $ O(h_0^2)$ approximation to $y(t_1)$

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like an order-reduced RK3 method. Using the standard Runge-Kutta notation, you get
\begin{align}
k_1&=hf(a,w_0),& w_1&=w_0+\tfrac12k_1\\
k_2&=hf(a+\tfrac12h,w_0+\tfrac12k_1),& w_2&=w_0+k_2\\
k_3&=hf(a+h,w_0+k_2)
\\\hline
y_{1,1}&=\tfrac12(w_1+w_2+\tfrac12k_3)\\
&=w_0+\tfrac14k_1+\tfrac12k_2+\tfrac14k_3
\end{align}
This then gives the Butcher tableau 
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
c_1 & \\
c_2 & a_{21}\\
c_3 & a_{31} & a_{32}\\\hline
&b_1&b_2&b_3
\end{array}
=
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
0 & \\
\tfrac12 & \tfrac12\\
1 & 0 & 1\\\hline
&\tfrac14&\tfrac12&\tfrac14
\end{array}
$$
where the first and second order conditions
$$
b_1+b_2+b_3=1\\
c_1b_1+c_2b_2+c_3b_3=\frac12
$$
are both satisfied.

See the Butcher's [tutorial on low-order methods](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/low-order-RK.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the initial value problem has the series

$$ y(a+h) = \alpha + f(a,\alpha) h + \frac{f_t(a,\alpha) + f(a,\alpha) f_y(a,\alpha)}{2} h^2 + O(h^3)$$

where $f_t = \partial f/\partial t$ and $f_y = \partial f/\partial y$. On the other hand, compute the series for $y_{11}$ and you should also find

$$y_{1,1} = \alpha + f(a,\alpha) h + \frac{f_t(a,\alpha) + f(a,\alpha) f_y(a,\alpha)}{2} h^2 + O(h^3)$$

Comment: is this error $O(h_0^3) $local error or global error ?        $y_{1,1}$ has apporoximating value $w_2,w_1$. then your taylor series is not global error?                 isn't it?

Comment: and it seemed to use Richard extrapolation. so I calcualte $ 2N(\frac{h_0}{2})-N(h_0)$. this result is not a  form $y_{1,1}$

Comment: @seyunkim : Are you sure it is Richardson extrapolation, and not extrapolation in the context of an embedded method?

Comment: $c_1b_1+c_2b_2+c_3b_3$ is not $ \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: i want know tutorial   but your pdf is difficult for me.

Comment: @seyunkim : Please comment below the text you want to comment on. Btw., $0\cdot\frac14+\frac12\cdot\frac12+1\cdot\frac14=\frac12$.